# How to get JQuery working with Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've added the the Jquery link from google, added rails ujs to my javascript libraries, added my javascript code index.js.erb in the same folder I have my index.erb file (view). 
My form has the form_tag and remote set to true.

And the javascript is not loading, I'm always forwarded as a normal get request.

Anything wrong or not working with rails3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

It will replace prototype handling with jQuery properly, my guess is that you currently have some conflict.

If not, consider adding:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.js
   format.html
end
```

Comment: afaik, that code block is deprecated now, in favor of responds_with at the controller level

Comment: Indeed, the doc still mentions respond_to: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript and I included the jquery-ujs js file, in my javascript folder. Although the prototype javascript is working fine, everytime i change it to jquery it stops working

Comment: Downloading straight from the link, downloaded the wrong file. I manually copy pasted the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the jquery-rails gem to replace all the default Prototype files with jquery libraries. Nice and quick solution.